# vb.net Convert this String to DateTime

Tags: vb.net, string, date, httpwebrequest

How can I convert this to date time?

```
Dim datestring As String = "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
```

I need to send in a HttpWebrequest, example

```
Dim requestAs HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(Link), WebRequest)
request.Method = "Post"
request.IfModifiedSince = datestring
```

but I can not because IfModifiedSince is type Date and i need to send exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with System.Date.Parse Method:

```
Dim datestring As String = "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
Dim requestAs HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(Link),    WebRequest)
request.Method = "Post"
' request.IfModifiedSince = datestring 
request.IfModifiedSince = Date.Parse(datestring )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Date.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) or `Date.TryParseExact`:

```
Dim dt As Date
If Date.TryParseExact(datestring, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortDateString())
End If
```

**Edit**: It seems that it also works with `Date.Parse( datestring )`